# Error de idioma al instalar Android Studio en Linux Mint 18.3

Tags: android, android-studio, linux

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de  instalar  android  Studio en Linux Mint 18.3 pero me  arroja las  palabras  como rectangulos. alguien puede  ayudarme porfavor

Comment: cual es el error no se ve ningun error en la imagen

Comment: las letras se  ven como cuadrados

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Comment: Preferences > Environment > Visual Style y seleccione el idioma = ¿has intentado algo para cambiar el idioma del IDE?

Comment: gracias por tratar de  ayudarme, pero no si te  das  cuenta  no puedo ver q opcion presiono pues solo s e ven cuadrados.. no sabria  como cambiarlo con click's

Comment: oh perdon, has intentado instalarlo con este tutorial de la comunidad de la distro : https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1953

Comment: Me late que es la fuente que usa el sistema

Answer (score -1):

Entra a la terminal y escribe

```
locale -a
```

Y muestra lo que te sale. Puede ser posible que falte habilitar una opcion en tus configuraciones de 'Locale'. Cuando los caracteres no salen como deberian esa configuracion es una de los primeros sospechosos.

Comment: Buenas por favor mejora tu respuesta, ve [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que la comunidad te entienda mejor y sea realmente aceptada.

Comment: esto me  sale  en la  terminal

Comment: C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
es_AR.utf8
es_BO.utf8
es_CL.utf8
es_CO.utf8
es_CR.utf8
es_CU
es_CU.utf8
es_DO.utf8
es_EC.utf8
es_ES.utf8
es_GT.utf8
es_HN.utf8
es_MX.utf8
es_NI.utf8
es_PA.utf8
es_PE
es_PE.iso88591
es_PE.utf8
es_PR.utf8
es_PY.utf8
es_SV.utf8
es_US.utf8
es_UY.utf8
es_VE.utf8
POSIX

Comment: Que sigue... se  agradece la r espuesta

Comment: Y si escribes solo 'locale' ?

Comment: LANG=es_PE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es_PE:es
LC_CTYPE="es_PE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_PE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_PE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="es_PE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_PE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="es_PE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_PE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_PE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_PE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_PE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_PE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_PE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

Comment: Parece que tendras que cambiar el idoma de tu sistema a ingles (Ahora esta en es de espanol), es muy probable que Android Studio use la codificacion LANG=en_US.UTF-8 y por eso tus caracteres salgan raros. La opcion para cambiar de idioma en Mint deberia estar en System -> preferences -> language support, es possible que instale mas idiomas y se solucione el problema; de lo contrario cambia a ingles. Una vez cambiado podrias buscar una configuracion en android studio para ponerlo en espanol (si existe dicha opcion) para luego volver a tu idoma anterior; eso si el ingles te causa otros errores.

Comment: hice lo de  cambiar  a ingles y es lo mismo, lo  volvi a instalar y nada :/